# arecord can't find the right device?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've installed the respeaker pi hat module to my Rpi0W using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
git clone https://github.com/respeaker/seeed-voicecard.git
cd seeed-voicecard
sudo ./install.sh
reboot
```

but cannot test whether it works -  The tutorial states I can pipe the recording and play it as such

```
arecord -f cd -Dhw:1 | aplay -Dhw:1
```

but this is not working? I guess my hardware is listed differently? but i can't figure out how i should make the same  call above with my hardware list?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -l && arecord -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 2: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1 [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: seeed2micvoicec [seeed-2mic-voicecard], device 0: bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: seeed2micvoicec [seeed-2mic-voicecard], device 0: bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

tutorial: http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker_2_Mics_Pi_HAT/

Answer (score 0):

I would first verify that you are running the appropriate operating system,

> Make sure that you are running the lastest Raspbian Operating System(debian 9) on your Pi. (updated at 2018.11.13)

I would also validate that the volume is set at the correct level, and that you have a speaker or earphones plugged in,

> Test, you will hear what you say to the microphones(don't forget to plug in an earphone or a speaker)

The volume can be set using `alsamixer` from the terminal.

Source: https://github.com/SeeedDocument/wiki_english/blob/master/docs/ReSpeaker_2_Mics_Pi_HAT.md#getting-started

Comment: Already tested..

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know the syntax, it looks like you arn't calling the device properly.
it should be something like this:

```
-D hw:1,0
```

as satated [here](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc) under "The naming of PCM devices"